# Comparing the slope at a point on P-V diagram with the isothermal slope at that point, can i predict whether the temperature is increasing or not?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read in my notes that seeing the slope of a process in a PV diagram and comparing it with the isothermal slope, we can predict that is the temperature increasing or decreasing at that point. But i haven't mentioned the reason or the result for that. Since i had taken up thermodynamics a long time ago i don't remember any explanation for this. 
Can anyone please help me confirm if this is true or not?

Also isothermal slope at that point be taken as P/V (just to clarify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Going from $A$ to $B$ the temperature is increasing.
You can compare the gradients and see that a less negative gradient than that of the isotherm will result in a higher temperature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why i did not think that.

Comment: Also is there a similar relation for heat( increasing or decresing) with the adiabatic slope at a point?

Comment: Heat does not increase or decrease as it is either heat entering a system or heat leaving a system.  The first law tells you that you can change the internal energy of a system by either doing work on a system or supplying heat to a system.

Comment: Sorry i meant , is it possible to know if the heat is being absorbed or released  by comparing the slope of graph with adiabatic slope at that point.

Answer (score 0):

(P, V1) be any point in the first curve with T1;
(P, V2) be the point in the next curve with T2;
The process is isothermal; 
PV1=mRT1;
PV2=mRT2;
P(V2-V1) = mR(T2-T1). (actually it is an isobaric curve); 
if T2 is higher than T1 the Rhs is to be positive
This implies the LHS is positive.ie V2-V1 is positive, V2>V1. hence The second curve is above the first one.

Comment: [We do have MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)